# Counting with more than 1 variable

Tags: excel, count, vba

I have a table with data. The data for column A is only 3,6,9. Column B is only open or closed. Then Column C are from A to J. Now, I need to count how many open or closed for each letter in column C. In Short, How many open and closed in account A, open and closed in account B,..., account J. I also want to count how many 3, 6, 9 per letter. But if given the codes for open and closed, I can just try to learn the code and come up with the codes for the 3,6,9. See sample table below. I would really appreciate the help. Please let me know if you need any additional info. Thank you very much!

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
3   Open    A
6   Closed  B
9   Closed  C
3   Open    D
6   Closed  E
9   Open    F
9   Closed  G
6   Closed  H
3   Closed  I
3   Open    J
3   Closed  A
6   Closed  B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTIF function:

```
Code Eg: =COUNTIF(B1:B12,"Open")
         =COUNTIF(B1:B12,"Closed")


Result: Open    4
        Closed  8
```

You can use this function to get a count for your other criterias as well

Click [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/count-how-often-a-value-occurs-HP001127779.aspx)!
Check this as well.

Comment: Hello Nishan. Thank you for your answer. However, I need to count how many open in A, how many closed in A, then how many open and closed in B, C, ... J.

Comment: =IF(AND(C11="A", B11="Closed"),COUNTIF(C11,"A"),0)
Do you want like this?